# Algolia Wordpress Limit Search to Post Titles only

Tags: wordpress, algolia

Is there a way to limit the search only to post titles with Algolia on Wordpress?

I need this for the autocomplete feature.

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely customize on what field the search will be based on.

First of all you have to let Algolia know that you only want to search on the post title field by changing the `attributesToIndex` setting:

```
/**
 * @param array $settings
 *
 * @return array
 */
function custom_posts_index_settings( array $settings ) {
    $settings['attributesToIndex'] = array( 'unordered(post_title)' );

    return $settings;
}

add_filter('algolia_posts_index_settings', 'custom_posts_index_settings');
add_filter('algolia_searchable_posts_index_settings', 'custom_posts_index_settings');
```

Then you need to customize the suggestions templates of the autocomplete by first moving the autocomplete.php file to your theme's folder like explained in this guide: https://community.algolia.com/wordpress/customize-autocomplete.html

Basically you will remove the part which looks like this one:

```
<#
            var attributes = ['content', 'title6', 'title5', 'title4', 'title3', 'title2', 'title1'];
            var attribute_name;
            var relevant_content = '';
            for ( var index in attributes ) {
            attribute_name = attributes[ index ];
            if ( data._highlightResult[ attribute_name ].matchedWords.length > 0 ) {
            relevant_content = data._snippetResult[ attribute_name ].value;
            break;
            } else if( data._snippetResult[ attribute_name ].value !== '' ) {
            relevant_content = data._snippetResult[ attribute_name ].value;
            }
            }
            #>
```

Comment: if I remove this whole part, then I get no autocomplete results.. do you mean i just need to remove the 'content' attribute ?

Comment: Do you mind sharing a live instance so that we can see the eventual errors?